# Ambient occlusion bake crashes blender (cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking, lighting

I can't get an ambient occlusion bake to work with my file; every time I try to bake, Blender crashes. I'm using cycles render, and my object is pretty low-poly. There might be some weird geometry in it, but the UV unwrap worked alright.

I'm using Blender 2.78 on a MacBook.

I've tried having the image texture node selected, both edit mode and object mode, checking and unchecking "clear", and creating a blank texture image to put the UV onto.

I'm absolutely new to Blender, so please let me know what other info is necessary! Here's the .blend: [image]

[image: settings and view of my working window]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason for the crash is [dupliframes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/duplication/dupliframes.html) (not really expected behaviour though).

The object has *Frames* enabled in the [Properties editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/properties_editor.html) > Object tab > *Duplication* rollout. It duplicates the object as many times as there are frames set (from 1 to 100), resulting in ~44 000 faces. It isn't visible as object is static.

[image: screenshot-red-line-below-None-point]

Also with this the object won't be renderable. Set the option to *None* and the bake will work.

There are some minor problems though in mesh geometry ([non-manifold geometry](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry/7914)) which are better to fix. Although they won't crash the bake:

1. Remove doubles (<kbd>W</kbd> > *Remove Doubles*) and recalculate normals (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>) first, this will remove some of the non-manifold geometry.
2. Edges overlayed on top of the faces (moved with Grab tool below for visualization purposes):

   [image: screennshot-grabbed-bad-geometry]

   To avoid UV map corruption delete one edge, then select vertices from the sides  and use *Connect Vertex Path* tool with <kbd>J</kbd> to split the face as it kind of was. Repeat for the other edges shown in the screenshot above.

   [image: screnshot-selected-healthy-edge-]

   Above selected edge was already made as mentioned.
3. Internal vertex inside of the mesh.

   [image: screenshot-bad-vertex]

   Above faces of the body are hidden to allow seeing through the mesh. Remove that vertex.